# Saving HTML Table Data Manipulated by JQUERY into ASP.NET (Preferably Session)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, vb.net, json

I have a few HTML tables and I am using jQuery to move/shuffle rows from one html table to another. Once the shuffling is completed, I need to find a way to save these tables on server side (preferably in Session) so that they can be retrieved on the next page.

As first step, I tried to save the altered DOM in ASP.NET Textbox so that I can bring the whole html onto ASP.NET side (and then process it using VB.NET code to save in session/cache).

```
var html = $('html').clone();
var htmlString = html.html();

$('#TextBox1').val(htmlString);
```

But I am stuck on the first step where I am getting the following error

"A potentially dangerous `Request.Form` value was detected from the client `TextBox1 ...`"

Could please someone guide me how can I save these HTML tables on server side so that I can use ASP.NET to read and process them? Should I look for JSON instead?

Comment: You can not pass html tags directly to the server as textbox value. Thats why you get this error.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to post the data of the table to the server, I usually convert the rows of my table to objects and post the data as JSON via ajax().  You can add a click event to trigger this automatically when the user presses a button that will trigger a postback or with any other event.

Example:

**Client Side**

```
    // Wire up posting the data to the server with a ASP.NET button
    $('#<%= Save.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
        PostTable();
    });


    // Read a row
    function GetRow(rowNum) {
        var tableRow = $('#partTable tbody tr').eq(rowNum);

        var row = {};

        row.ChangeType = tableRow.find('td:eq(1)').text();
        row.UpdateType = tableRow.find('td:eq(2)').text();
        row.Part = tableRow.find('td:eq(5)').text();
        row.Price = tableRow.find('td:eq(7)').text();
        row.UOM = tableRow.find('td:eq(8)').text();
        row.ApplyDate = tableRow.find('td:eq(9)').text();
        row.Remarks = tableRow.find('td:eq(10)').text();

        return row;
    }

    // Read all rows
    function GetAllRows() {
        var dataRows = [];

        $('#partTable tbody tr').each(function (index, value) {
            var currentRow = GetRow(index);
            dataRows.push(currentRow);
        });

        return dataRows;
    }

    // POST rows to server
    function PostTable() {
        var crossId = getParameterByName('id');
        var jsonRequest = { rows: GetAllRows(), crossId: crossId };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'TableProcessingViajQueryAjax.aspx/SaveRows',
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonRequest),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (data, text) {
                return true;
            },
            error:function (request, status, error){
                return false;
            }
```

**Server Side**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool SaveRows(List<Row> rows, int crossId)
    {
        // Do something with your data, maybe put in session/cache/db/etc...
    }
```

**Server Side ( Object must match object created in JS )**

```
public class Row
{
    public string ChangeType { get; set; }
    public string UpdateType { get; set; }
    public string Part { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int UOM { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApplyDate { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

** I'm using JSON.ORG's "stringify" to convert my object into a valid JSON object.

Comment: Zachary, this is exactly what I am trying to achieve. I have html tables (which were manipulated using JQUERY). I would now like to save them on ASP.NET. I will try your approach and will update you of the results.

Answer (score 1):

One way to work around this without the disabling the Request validation is to encode the HTML data into something that ASP.NET wouldn't detect as a potential dangerous request. Such option is [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.

Since you are already using jquery; you can easily take the html and encode it using one of the many base64 plugins ([one example here](https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64)).

Now all you need to do is:

```
$('#TextBox1').val(base64encodedhtmlString);
```

And convert it back on the server side as so:

```
string encodedstring = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(text.Text));
```

Assuming your page uses utf-8 encoding as in: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

**Note**: This "solution" is a hack. I would look for an alternative to do what you need without doing something like this. It smells.

**UPDATE**:

Adding a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JXFJU/) for you. Pay attention to the "Manage Resources" section. I am using the plugin I linked above.

You can take the output from my example (`PHRhYmxlIGlkPSJzb21ldGFibGUiIGNlbGxwYWRkaW5nPSI1IiBib3JkZXI9IjIiPgogIDx0Ym9keT48dHI+CiAgICAgPHRkPmJsYWg8L3RkPgogICAgIDx0ZD5ibGFoPC90ZD4KICAgICA8dGQ+YmxhaDwvdGQ+CiAgIDwvdHI+CjwvdGJvZHk+PC90YWJsZT4=`) and [decoded it here](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) to verify that it actually contains the original html.

Comment: Thanks. so what lines of code should I add to the following code then var html = $('html').clone();
            var htmlString = html.html();

            $('#TextBox1').val(htmlString);

Comment: I added the following line  $.base64.encode(htmlstring); but it didn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this solution:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

But validate request check potentially dangerous requests
Also you can read [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/234664-potentially-dangerous-requestform-value-was-detected-from-the-client/).

Comment: I tried ValidateRequest="false" but still getting the same "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value" error

Comment: I had to make this change to the webconfig to have validateRequest working <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a HiddenField instead of a TextBox?  I can't recall if you get the "potentially dangerous Request.Form value" with a HiddenField.  I'm thinking it probably still does.

Regardless, I'd try using JSON instead of trying to send the code for an HTML table (which would be more difficult to parse on the server side).  You can use jQuery to manipulate your data and save in javascript variables (array of objects?) instead of directly modifying the HTML tables; then rebuild your HTML table displays based on those variables.

You can serialize your data on the client as JSON (JSON.stringify) and send it to the server in a HiddenField.  Then on the server you can use the JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize it and handle that data on the server.  On another page, you could create another HiddenField and use the JavaScriptSerializer to serialize your data into the HiddenField; then your client code could deserialize the JSON to get the data loaded into variables and rebuild the HTML table displays using those variables.

JSON2 Example...

```
// Serialize
var value_for_hidden_field = JSON.stringify(my_js_variable);  
$("#HiddenField1").val(value_for_hidden_field); 

// Deserialize
var my_js_variable = JSON.parse($("#HiddenField1").val());
```

ASP.Net Example...
This is overly simplified, because you'd need to use a Class you have set up to handle your data, but it gives you the general idea of the methods you'd call.

```
' Deserialize
Dim jss As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim json_x  = jss.Deserialize(Of YourClassName)(HiddenField1.Value)

' Serialize
Dim jss As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim json_x As New YourClassName = GetYourData() ' Returning appropriate object
HiddenField1.Value = jss.Serialize(json_x)
```

Comment: Tried using hiddenfield, same error. Do you have a sample code for JSON that could be used for this particular problem?

Comment: For JavaScript, I'm using 'json2.js' which can be found at http://www.json.org/. This library you to use JSON.stringify to serialize javascript variables (arrays/objects) into JSON (which can then be stored in the HiddenField) and JSON.deserialize to convert the JSON string into javascript objects which can be stored in variables.  For ASP.Net, I'm using the JavaScriptSerializer class to deserialize the JSON string sent to the server and to serialize the ASP.Net objects that I want to store in a HiddenField to make them available to the client page.

Comment: Thanks, I am assuming I need to first bring all those values in table cells into variables and then start saving them into json objects.I have the whole table loaded in a string in jquery. Any idea how can I read that string and load all the values in jquery variables first? OR SHould I save the whole html into my_js_variable ?

Comment: Do you initially fill your HTML table with data from the server?  If so, how do you go about doing that?

Comment: 1- Write HTML tables (fed through arraylist) 2- Use JQuery to shuffle rows in between html tables  3- Find a mechanism to save these shuffled tables to ASP.NET (so that data can be cached/stored in session). I was trying to save the whole html into ASP.NET variable and that's why using Textbox or any other data control in Jquery to write the whole DOM to it and then retrieve it from ASP.NET side.

Comment: Okay, so you have an ArrayList of data your using to fill your HTML tables. I was envisioning using generic list of objects to store your data on the server. So you'd have a Class to hold your data (for one row of table) and then a List (Of YourClass) to hold your various objects (each one representing a row of data). With this List (Of YourClass), you'd then be able to serialize it to place in your HiddenField. When your JavaScript pulls it out of the HiddenField and deserializes it, you'd then have an array of objects in JavaScript which you could use to fill your HTML table (via jQuery).